# VBA to remove part of the same cell's content on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove the first half of a formula on multiple sheets throughout a workbook. Four specific cells per sheet (F308, F315, F322, F329) need to have just the first part of the formula removed.

The formula is: ='Project Input - John1'!$D$954*'Project Input - John1'!$D$952

The major catch here is each cells formula on each sheet, while extremely similar, is different. Each sheet referred to is different on each sheet and each referring cell is different in every cell.

I don't want to change the unique second part, just remove the first part: 'Project Input - John1'!$D$954*. or everything before (and including) *.

Is it possible to create a workbook formula to do this where I only have to run it once? If not, is it possible to do it sheet by sheet with a standard reference like, "This sheet"? Thanks!

Edit:
I have tried to record a macro but it applied the last part of the formula from the cell I recorded it in

I tried this VBA:

```
Sub test()
tx = Split(Cells(6, 315), "4")
For i = LBound(tx) To UBound(tx)
Cells(1, 2) = tx(i)
Next
End Sub
```

and this:

```
Dim ichar As Integer ichar = InStr(1, cl.Value, afterString, vbTextCompare) 
cl = Left(cl.Value, ichar + Len(afterString) -1) 
End Sub 

Sub test() Call removetextbefore("*", Sheet11.Cell(f308)) 
End Sub
```

I got a compile error

I'm trying to find code that works and have scoured the sites, but nothing is seeming to work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are definitely examples out there that do things just like this

Comment: No.  A workbook formula can only return a result to the cell in which it is located.  It cannot change other cells.  You can write VBA Macro which should be able to check the relevant cells on all your worksheets, changing the formula according to whatever rules you want.  If you have trouble after writing the macro, post back with your issues.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2  I tried the following:


Dim ichar As Integer

ichar = InStr(1, cl.Value, afterString, vbTextCompare)


cl = Left(cl.Value, ichar + Len(afterString) -1)


End Sub


Sub test()

Call removetextbefore("*", Sheet11.Cell(f308))


End Sub 

I got a compile error

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I tried recording a macro but it replaced the unique cell contents with the contents of the cell I recorded it on.

Comment: please add your code to your question via an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53106900/edit)

Comment: Among other issues, you have your rows and columns argument reversed in your `Cells` statement. `Cells(6, 315).address --> $LC$6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do something like this, using the `Split` method:

```
Sub editFormulas()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With WS
    For Each R In Union(.Cells(308, 6), .Cells(315, 6), .Cells(322, 6), .Cells(329, 6))
        R.Formula = "=" & Split(R.Formula, "*")(1)
    Next R
End With
Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. I added this in and got a "Run-Time error 9: Subscript out of range". I'm looking into this now

Comment: With that limited information, hard to tell what the problem is. If the formula in the referenced cell does not contain an `*`, you'll get that message. Or, since you wrote you "added this in", it could be coming from something having nothing to do with this code, but rather with the code to which you added it.

Comment: I'm realizing now that not all the sheets in this book have that formula, for example my summary and parameter sheets. is there a way to make this code for just the sheet I put the code in for?

Thanks for your help and patience on this!!

Comment: @charitytowin There are many ways to do that.  You could check the worksheet name (or `Codename`) within the `For` loop; you could check each formula to see if contained an `*`.  You could check for the error in obtaining `Split(R.Formula, "*"),1` and other methods I have not mentioned.